# How to listen the page beforeunload or unload event in android webview by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I use a WebView to load my page below：

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>first page</h1>
        <script>
            (function(){
                function log(e){
                    console.log("Page is going to unload："+e);
                }
                window.addEventListener('beforeunload',log);
                window.addEventListener('unload',log);
            })()
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

this page has worked well in Chrome or other PC-browser。

Here is the code in activity：

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView web;
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        web = findViewById(R.id.web);
        web.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        WebSettings webSettings = web.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        web.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.103:5000/WebContent/");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.i("SSSS","acitvity destroyed");
        super.onDestroy();
        ConstraintLayout layout = this.findViewById(R.id.rootView);
        layout.removeView(web);
        web.destroy();
        web = null;
    }

}
```

when leave the activity that contains WebView ，I cannot catch any logs about page unload event，is anything wrong？

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this but based on the documentation you need to override [WebChromeClient::onConsoleMessage](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onConsoleMessage(android.webkit.ConsoleMessage)) and use [WebView::setWebChromeClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#setWebChromeClient(android.webkit.WebChromeClient)).

Comment: It doesn't matter. Overriding WebChromeClient::onConsoleMessage  just makes the console log look like the app native log

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are removing view and Webview in `onDestroy`

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.i("SSSS","acitvity destroyed");
        super.onDestroy();
        ConstraintLayout layout = this.findViewById(R.id.rootView);
        layout.removeView(web);   <----- This linse
        web.destroy(); <------ Forcing webview to destroy and next explicitly set null
        web = null;
    }
```

Comment: I tried what you said,still couldn't catch the page unload event. I remove and destroy the Webview because of the Webview still running in the background even though the activity already has been destroyed. 
I cannot wait for GC.